# How the determine the most frequently occuring tags in an XML file with standard tools (Unix or Windows)?

Tags: xml, unix, xslt, tags, frequency

Given an XML file, I am interested to find out what are the most often occurring XML tags in it. A sorted list of all XML tags ordered by occurrence would be sufficient.

Is there any way to achieve this with standard tools, thinking of grep and other Unix tools or a smart approach under Window. XSLT would be okay as long as there is an easy way of running it (not creating a dedicated Java project for it).

Limitation: the XML may be big (hundreds of Megabytes).

Comment: Show us some examples of input and output - in particular what counts as "the same".  If the file contains `<foo type="a">` and `<foo type="b">` is that two instances of the tag "foo" or two different tags?

Comment: If you're not allowed to write a program to do it (which is the obvious solution), should this question even be on SO?

Comment: Ian, your example would be two instances of the tag "foo". So, for `<foo a="5"><foo a="6" /><bar></bar></foo><foobar/>` I would expect 2x foo, 1x bar, 1x foobar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to get all tag names, then uniquify the list.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//*' -c "name(.)" -n input.xml | \
  sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```